# objective-c: getting source code from binary

Tags: decompilation, ios

I posted a question a few time ago but answers were not clear to me and the topic was closed because apparently the request was not clear:

SO I clarify it: One upon a time a wrote a obj-c app but now I only have binary, don't know where I put the source code!

Can you guide me step-by-step in order to retrive the source code from the binary?

[image]

otools gives:
[image]
so the binary is luckly not encrypted

Thanks

Comment: No. You cannot retrieve "the" source code from a compiled binary. Unfortunately, if the answers in your original question were not clear to you then that's what it is, here and now.

Comment: Use the IDA ARM Decompiler?

Answer (score 3):

With a lot of manual correction you can most probably get "a" source code, in assembly language as a first step.  That may be all you need to provide whatever support you need to do.

To get "a" source code in Objective-C or in any higher language you will have to analyse the structure of your working assembly program and translate it into the language of your choice.

However it will never be "the" original source code, in all its glory.